# How to make App Available for use

Tags: facebook

I have an App which I have made "public" on the Status and Review tab ("make this app and all its live features available to the general public?")

How can a user select this App for use?  When a user, currently unrelated to the App logs in there is no way of browsing to this App.

Do I need to go through a registration process as well as making it "public"?  If so how do I do this

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear!

Comment: I have made the App public. How does a facebook user discover my App ?

Comment: You have to do the marketing of your app, how else one could find your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was after

Go to settings/Apps/App Settings/Apps You Use/'Visibility of App'/Public